# How to get http url of downloaded file in android?

Tags: android, file, http, url, download

I am trying to find a way to get http-url of downloaded file in android. Is there anyway to do it ? 
I have looked around DownloadManager, but it seems not appropriate for this scenario.

e.g. if we open browser with link : http://www.xyz.com/myapp.apk?param1=abc
and now after downloading and installing apk. 
In same application (when it starts) I need to get -> param1=abc.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Who is downloading this file? If the file is downloaded in your app, you can store the url in an variable (or in the database) when the file is downloaded. What do you think about?

Comment: Yeah, that is a problem; My application is not downloading this file, this is default browser which downloads it. "myapp.apk" is the one which actually gonna use its own url-link (from where it has downloaded)

Comment: Not sure it's possible. Besides, nothing guaranties the file has been downloaded by the default browser. Many people use another browser (Dolphin, Chrome, etc...) and each one might use a different way to download the file. An option would be, server side, to give the field a different name at download time. eg. myapp-abc.apk or myapp-def.apk depending on the param value. But again, nothing would be guaranties (the user could rename the file).

Comment: Another option would be to have a different apk for each possible value and in the resources of the apk, set a variable with the value That option depends on how many possible values you have and if they are pre-defined by you. More details on the type of parameter/value that is going to be passed could help giving more options

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Do you want different modes of operation based on which link the apk file was downloaded from?  Sounds like multiple apk files (as @Benoit) mentioned is a better choice for this.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I think that the downloaded url is not stored in the .apk file. The apk file is a portable file and can be downloaded from different url addresses and the web browser will not add a metadata to the apk file.